# How to set content type to html on Google Calendar api?

Tags: zend-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

So reading the google calendar api (php) documentation it states:

"...content, set using setContent, provides additional information about the event which appears when the event details are requested from within Google Calendar. Optionally,   **the description's mime-type is set using  setType to specify HTML instead of plain text.** "

I've been trying to figure this out for a really long time but i have no idea how to go about setting the content to html instead of plan text. I tried using the setType method, on Zend_Gdata_Calendar object, but it said the method doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the API there is a section that talks about "Creating web content events."  That shows an example of setting the type, which is just a MIME type.  For HTML, you can set the type as "text/html" and then provide the link to the HTML.

[Data API Developer's Guide: PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html)

From reading it, I believe this will create an iFrame that shows your content.  I've been playing around with this a lot in .NET and it seems to work.  I hope this helps you.